# Jenkins execute part of shell script

Tags: jenkins

I am using this script to upgrade my app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

set -e

set -x


JAVA_HOME="/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211"
APP_HOME="/data/jenkins/soa-robot-service"
APP_NAME="soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

PID=`ps -ef|grep -w ${APP_NAME}|grep -v grep|cut -c 9-15`
if [[ ${PID} -gt 1 ]]; then
        kill -9 ${PID}
        sleep 5
else
        echo "Process not found"
fi

count=`ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [[ ${count} -lt 1 ]]; then
  cd ${APP_HOME}
  nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx512M -Xms256M -jar \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt \
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 \
  ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> ${APP_HOME}/soa-robot.log &
else
  echo "process aready exists!"
  exit 1
fi
```

When I am execute in terminal,it works fine.When I am executing in Jenkins (Jenkins ver. 2.164.3)using remote ssh(by using jenkins plugin),this is the command:

```
# add executable privillege
chmod +x /data/jenkins/soa-room-service/upgrade.sh
# upgrade app
/bin/bash /data/jenkins/soa-room-service/upgrade.sh
```

It only execute part of the shell script,this is the output:

```
[SSH] script:

# add executable privillege
chmod +x /data/jenkins/soa-room-service/upgrade.sh
# upgrade app
/bin/bash /data/jenkins/soa-room-service/upgrade.sh

[SSH] executing...
+ JAVA_HOME=/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211
+ APP_HOME=/data/jenkins/soa-room-service
+ APP_NAME=soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
++ ps -ef
++ grep -w soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
++ grep -v grep
++ cut -c 9-15
+ PID=' 16309 '
+ [[  16309  -gt 1 ]]
+ kill -9 16309
+ sleep 5
++ grep soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
++ grep -v grep
++ ps -ef
++ wc -l
+ count=0
+ [[ 0 -lt 1 ]]
+ cd /data/jenkins/soa-room-service

[SSH] completed
[SSH] exit-status: 0

Finished: SUCCESS
```

this last command does not execute(finally the app dit not run).But when I run the second time,the script execute perfect.This make me very confusion, where is the problem?What should I do to fix?

Comment: Can you show how you execute it? Do you use a Jenkinsfile or a scripted pipeline?

Comment: I am added my way to using shell script,not jenkinsfile.@mkemmerz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to remove nohup and & from the command after cd ${APP_HOME}.
Seems like output is not getting captured in stdout as the process in running in background inside Jenkins shell.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason about why the nohup command not execute.When I am executed nohup command,the nohup need time to start command.If you logout or exit too fast,It may cause the nohup do not have enough time to start background process.So solve this problem,you should try to add some command after nohup command,like:

```
sleep 3
```

finally the script may like this:

```
count=`ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [[ ${count} -lt 1 ]]; then
  cd ${APP_HOME}
  nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx512M -Xms256M -jar \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt \
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 \
  ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> ${APP_HOME}/soa-robot.log &
  sleep 3
else
  echo "process aready exists!"
  exit 1
fi
```